# Is it correct to ask "How does that has anything to do with me?"

Tags: grammaticality, questions

I am having a doubt about whether these questions are correctly phrased or not:

> 1. How does that has anything to do with me?
> 2. How does that had anything to do with me?
> 3. What does that has anything to do with me?

Did I phrase it correctly?

Comment: @user178049: [It's not proofreading when there's a few specific points they're asking about](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/stop-throwing-proofreading-close-reason-at-questions-that-are-clearly-limited). Research *is* encouraged, but in this case lack of research would only be cause for downvoting, not closing.

Answer (score 2):

You're very close with your first sentence.

It should be

> How does that **have** anything to do with me?

I think the confusion here is around have/has.

For example, the statement

> He has a good job

Uses **has**, following the normal verb conjugation rules (I have, you have, he has, she has, it has, we have, they have, etc.)

**The trick is**, that when you turn it into a question, you don't conjugate the verb. The verb is **to have**, so when it's a question it just stays as **have**

> Does he **have** a good job?

This applies to all verbs

For example with the verb **to eat**,

> He **eats** very quickly

turns into

> Does he **eat** very quickly?

---

As for the other two sentences,

> How does that had anything to do with me?

**had** is the wrong tense here, the past tense specifically. If you wanted to phrase it in the past tense, you could say

> How **did that have** anything to do with me?

Finally,

> What does that has anything to do with me?

The **has** should be **have**, as I explained above, but if you want to phrase the question with **what**, you can simply leave out **anything** and say

> What **does that have** to do with me?

Comment: Thank you sir for you through explanation , I understand now.

Comment: I believe that you’re missing the point a little (and, so, your answer is misleading). It’s not simply the case that questions use a non-conjugated form of the verb. It’s that most questions are formed by creating an emphatic form, with the auxiliary **do**, and inverting it. So, while we can say, “He has a good job,” we can also say, “He *does* have a good job,” using the non-conjugated (bare infinitive) *have*. That’s why “How does that has …” is wrong. But questions that don’t use auxiliary verbs do conjugate their main verb; for example, “Who goes there?” or “What animal eats grass?”

Comment: You're correct, and those are all very good points. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: As a non-native speaker, I was taught that once you used a modal auxiliary verb in your sentence, the main verb should always be in its basic form. So, *What DOES that/it HAVE to do with me?* Or, *What DO those/these/they HAVE to do with me?* Or, *What DID it (other pronouns) HAVE to do with me?* are correct, right?

Comment: Yeah you're correct, I probably could have explained it more thoroughly